# Getting null string while AES decryption in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, aes

I am implementing AES encryption on my angular project and decrypting the same in my dotnet code.
Instead of relying on implicit derivation(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, password)), explicitly did that using PBKDF2. I can't understand where exactly this is failing.

**Encryption in Angular side using crypto-js:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CryptoService {
private secretkey = "MyOwnKey";

encrypt(text: string): string {
    // random salt for derivation
    let keySize = 256;
    let salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    // well known algorithm to generate key
    let key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(this.secretkey, salt, {
        keySize: keySize/32,
        iterations: 100
        });
    // random IV
    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);      
    // specify everything explicitly
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, { 
        iv: iv, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC        
    });
    // combine everything together in base64 string
    let result = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(salt.concat(iv).concat(encrypted.ciphertext));
    return result;
}
}
```

**Decryption in Dotnet side:**

```
public string decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            return string.Empty;
        
        try
        {
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                // extract salt (first 16 bytes)
                byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                Array.Copy(cipherBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
                _logger.LogInformation("salt: {salt}", salt);

                // extract iv (next 16 bytes)
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                Array.Copy(cipherBytes, 16, iv, 0, 16);
                _logger.LogInformation("iv: {iv}", iv);

                // the rest is encrypted data
                byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipherBytes.Length - 32];
                Array.Copy(cipherBytes, 32, encrypted, 0, cipherBytes.Length - 32);
                _logger.LogInformation("encrypted: {encrypted}", encrypted);

                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MyOwnKey", salt, 100);
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                encryptor.IV = iv;

                string plaintext;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            reader?.Dispose();
                        }
                        cs?.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                var cbLength = plaintext.Length;
                _logger.LogInformation("plaintext Lenght: {cbLength}", cbLength);
                return plaintext;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Decryption error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

When I call this decrypt method, I am getting a null string. Why is that so?

Comment: Is the plaintext actually valid utf-8 encoded bytes? A [mre], with plaintext, might be necessary.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk actually the plaintext is null only. I checked the logs, it's returning null value

Comment: I meant the plaintext *before* it is **encrypted** by the Javascript code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, it is valid utf-8 encoded bytes

Comment: Best thing to do is to compare the key, IV and ciphertext on both sides. If the key is incorrect you can start looking at the parameters of PBKDF2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MyOwnKey", salt, 100);`

to

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MyOwnKey", salt, 100,  HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);`